# 16GB SD card showing up as 0 bytes in size, 0 bytes free - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, sd-card

I have a fairly new 16GB SD card, my laptop runs Windows 7. I want to experiment using it for ReadyBoost. So this morning I went to delete all the files from it to clean it up. There were many 1000s of files, so this was going to take quite a while. I cancelled that procedure, then did a quick format from the laptop. Now the card is showing up as 0 bytes in capacity with 0 bytes free. I can take it to another Windows 7 machine and it shows up as the full 16GB in size.

How can I get the card to be recognized correctly on the laptop?

Comment: Do you have the card reader drivers installed on the original laptop? I have had similar issue and found that there was a driver missing for the card reader.

Comment: Both machines have built in SD card slots, so not sure if there's a driver available for that on-board hardware.  Now the first PC doesn't even show the SD card at all.

Comment: What is the laptop that does not see the card?

Comment: It's not showing up on the original laptop that I want to try the ReadyBoost from.

Comment: Yes, I understand. What make and model laptop are you trying to get the card read from?( HP XXX?, Lenovo, Alienware?)

Comment: Dell Inspiron Core i5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you check out [Dell support](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/ProductSelector/Select/FamilySelection?CategoryPath=all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop&Family=Inspiron&DisplayCrumbs=Product%2bType@,Laptops@,Inspiron&rquery=na&sokey=solink) and find your exact model. There are drivers for the card reader for whatever particular i5 inspirion you have. Look under the "Chipset" link and ensure you get the one for your OS.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Today the card started working, I didn't change anything.  Oh well.